# Google Region tags?

Tags: google, google-search-console, top-level-domains, google-ranking

I own 2 domains, both are for the same company. However one is for the USA and one is for the UK.  They both have the same name, the only difference is the TLD, for example

`mycompany.co.uk` (UK) and `mycompany.com` (USA)

Unfortunately, in many cases, the USA website is actually ranking above the UK site on `google.co.uk`

How can I show Google that

1. Both sites are the same company
2. That one is a UK site and one is a USA site.  I have heard that it's
   possible to include some kind of tag on our site to show this.

Answer (score 2):

In Google Webmaster Tools you should set a [geographic target](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/62399?hl=en) for each website:

1. On the Webmaster Tools Home page, click the site you want.
2. Click the gear icon [image], and then click Site Settings.
3. In the Geographic target section, select the option you want.